# Displaying the link under the image

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying a set of thumbnail images with links on a webpage like this

[image]

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="newsletters-and-journals">
    <p id="pubs-caption">Publications</p>
    <ul>
        <li class="pubs">
            <img class="pub-cover" src="images/CXuyv.png" />
            <span><a href="#">Journal - January 2012</a></span>
        </li>
        <li class="pubs">
            <img class="pub-cover" src="images/vER9H.png" />
            <span><a href="#">Newsletter - May 2012</a></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

and the CSS

```
#newsletters-and-journals ul { position:relative; top:12px; left:30px; }
.pubs { display:inline; margin-right:60px; }
.pub-cover { width:120px; height:140px; }​
```

also a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nK0de/3jeVF/2/

How can I display the links **under** each corresponding image?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also works:

```
.pubs {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 60px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

`width` is your image's width.

Answer (score 0):

You can make either `<img>` or `<span>` to `display:block`

http://jsfiddle.net/3jeVF/6/

Comment: Thanks but I need to images to be side by side while only links display under each of them.

Answer (score 0):

to solve your problem just add a 
br
tag in between 
     img and span tag.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried but did not work. Besides I'm trying my best to keep off presentational tags off the code as much as possible and do the styling from CSS.